# Wrong parameter from URL after navigating in Angular

Tags: angular

I am working with Angular 2 and I have the following problem.

On a few buttons, I have a redirect function to move to another page.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-xs" *ngFor="let pl of results;let i=index" (click)="onButtonClick(pl.pl_id)">{{i+1}}</button>
```

**Then on my component I have those functions:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = +params['id']; 
    });
    ...
    ...
}

onButtonClick(id) {
    this._router.navigate(['/app/data', id]);        
    this.ngOnInit();
}
```

The reason I call ngOnInit after the navigation is that if I don't, the URL changes, but the content of the page stays the same.

So, the problem here is that the `ngOnInit` get's the parameter of the previous url and not the one after the `navigate`.

For example, I am on url `/app/data/1` and I click on the button with the function `onButtonClick(2)`.

The URL changes to `/app/data/2` but the content is those from `/app/data/1`. If I click again on the same button, it gets the right content. Same for all the other buttons.

My thoughts are that `navigate` needs some time to update the URL and the `ngOnInit` is faster and gets the parameter from the current URL and not the new one.

Any idea?

**Edit:**
I found this answer from another question but without a fix on it:

*So, for example, navigating from /component/1 to /component/2, where the url is mapped to the same component (but with different params) will cause the router to instantiate an instance of Component when you navigate to /component/1, and then re-use that same instance when you navigate to /component/2. Based on what you're describing (where ngOnInit is only being called once), it seems as though this is what you're encountering.*

As for the routes config, those are the specific componenent's module. If you need more, let me know.

```
export const routes = [
  {path: 'archive', component: archivedContests, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]},
  {path: ':id', component: editContest, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]},
  {path: '', component: Contests, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]}


];
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: @ArmanAsghari Nothing. I just see the wrong links on Network tab, I call later on the `ngOnInit` with the previous URL parameter.

Comment: Does your componet implement `OnInit`?  I mean what's the purpose of calling `this.ngOnInit()` manually?

Comment: Yes. My component implements `OnInit` but as I said, if I don't put the `this.ngOnInit()` there, the content doesn't update when the URL changes with the navigate.

Comment: This question is about Routing but where is your routing configuration ???

Comment: @TekTimmy Updated my question. Thanks

Comment: @Tasos, put the code inside the ngOnInit inside the constrctor(), would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### params.map()

You may call `map()` on `route.params`.

Also, as `route.params` is an `observable` assign it to a `Subscription`. Take a look here:

```
sub: Subscription;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {    
        this.sub = this.route.params
            .map(params => params['id'])
            .subscribe(id => this.id = id);
    }
```

Another resulotion would be calling `router.navigateByUrl()` instead of `router.navigate()`;

Comment: Nope. It doesn't help. Still the same issue

Comment: If I add the rest of the ngOnInit code inside the subscribe of the above code, then it works as it should.